# What is the difference between resizing the browser window and using 'responsive design view'?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm currently developing a website and am using media queries to adjust the layout.

However, I have noticed that I need to go into Mozilla's '**Responsive Design View**' to get an accurate representation of how the layout would resize typically on mobile devices.

Resizing the browser window does not always have the same effect. What is the difference between these two?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla Responsive Design view adapt to different screen sizes to provide a presentation that is suitable for different kinds of devices, such as mobile phones or tablets. Responsive Design Mode makes it easy to see how your website or web app will look on different screen sizes.

Resizing the browser can have the same effect but is less convenient and affects the tabs as well.

Therefore the Responsive Design View is a convenience that you should take advantage off instead of resizing the browser itself.

Answer (score 0):

Respnsonsive design view of mozilla serves the same purpose of just resizing the browser itself.

Comment: But the OP is saying that they don't " always have the same effect"